# TypeError: e[l] is null

Tags: javascript

I have following code to iterate a javascript object:

```
for (var ke in data) {
                 if ( data[ke].key == "P_MATCHCOUNT")
                 {
                    console.log(ke);
                    //dosomething

                 } 
              }
```

I am getting error like:

> TypeError: e[l] is null
>       "linear")}));for(var l in e)"P_MATCHCOUNT"==e[l].key&&console.log(l)}}))

The json array is:

```
edit

    "Y"
key

    "P_MATCHCOUNT"
label

    ""
label_val

    ""
screenBit

    ""
value

    2982
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Solution:

As @Manoz pointed out, `data[ke]` was null in some cases. I had to add:

```
if ( data[ke] !== null )
```

to solve this.

Comment: is this `for(var l in e)"P_MATCHCOUNT"==e[l].key&&console.log(l)}})` your code?

Comment: yes, minified version is shown in error code.

Comment: `e[l] is null --> data[ke] is null`

Comment: I need to add a check for this. I solved. thanks.

Comment: is it solved? add an answer for future users by yourself if its fixed.